# Call to undefined method Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Registry::persist()

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-2.1

I recently upgraded one of my projects from Symfony 2.0.x to 2.1.x

Everything works fine, but when I try to persist an entity in a service, PHP throws an error:

`Call to undefined method Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Registry::persist()`

In the controllers, everything works fine. Even fetching objects from db in a service works, but no call to `->persist($entity)`.

This is my service definition:

```
registration_form:
    class: KnowHow\ERegistration\BackendBundle\Service\RegistrationFormService
    arguments: [ @doctrine ]
```

And my class:

```
 class RegistrationFormService
 {
     /** @var $em \Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager */
     private $em;

     /**
      * Ctor.
      *
      * @param $doctrine
      */
     public function __construct($doctrine)
     {
        $this->em = $doctrine;
     }
}
```

This is okay, but when I try to do something like thi `$this->em->persist($entity)` the error gets thrown.

I have no idea what's going on there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to inject `@doctrine.orm.entity_manager` for what you're trying to do

```
registration_form:
    class: KnowHow\ERegistration\BackendBundle\Service\RegistrationFormService
    arguments: [ @doctrine ]
               ----^ (isn't good)
```

modify it to

```
registration_form:
    class: KnowHow\ERegistration\BackendBundle\Service\RegistrationFormService
    arguments: [ @doctrine.orm.entity_manager ]
```

alternatively, you have to use do somthing like this (in your constructor)

```
public function __construct(Doctrine $doctrine)
{
    $this->em = $doctrine->getEntityManager();
}
```

As Cyprian suggest, I'll add the type of `$doctrine` variable for type checking. Don't know if `Doctrine` is the right class, but I suppose it is

I suggest to inject only `entity_manager` if you don't need the whole `doctrine` vendor

Comment: I just add that IMO it's also good idea strongly type arguments you inject (eg. public function __construct(Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager $doctrine)). It really could help you avoid this kind mistakes in future.

Comment: @Cyprian you're right, i'll add it (but it isn't of the class you're suggest :D)

Comment: @DonCallisto I've suggest phpdoc above property, and name of service from your answer ("docrine.orm.entity_manager" refers to EntityManager). Of course name of service to doctrine registry is "doctrine". :)